# Pandas Dataframe with Images to xlsx

Tags: python, image, dataframe, xlsx, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to store images in a pandas dataframe which are rendered when the dataframe is converted to xlsx? Something like:

```
from PIL.Image import Image

df = pd.DataFrame({'img': [Image.open('pic.jpg')]})
df.to_excel('image.xlsx')
```

The problem is that only the python image objects and not the image itself is exported.

I know that there is a workaround with `worksheet.insert_image` but I'd prefere working with the dataframe.